# Redirect only domain.com to a subfolder?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Hi i would like to redirect **only** the domain.com (not www.domain.com) to a subfolder

I tried:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^?YourDomain.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ page [L]
```

but it gave an internal server error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 500 internal server error is caused by a bad expression:

```
# what's this? -----------v
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^?YourDomain.com$
```

Not sure what you're trying to do with that question mark. But you probably want something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^YourDomain.com$ [NC]
```

The `[NC]` makes it case insensitive.